# Playwright: Test times out waiting for an element to be visible even though the elements before it were found

Tags: typescript, playwright, playwright-test

When I try to find an input box, my test times out. The elements before the card number can be found, but the card number gives me timeout issues. My code is below:

```
await expect(page).toHaveURL("https://app.pws.int.cruk.org/support-us/payment");
  await page.waitForLoadState("domcontentloaded");
  page.waitForTimeout(10000)

  const card = page.getByText("Credit / Debit");
  const cardholder = page.locator("#cardholderName");
  const cardnumber = page.getByRole('textbox', { name: 'credit-card-number' });

  const giftaid = page.getByText("Yes I would like Cancer Research UK to claim Gift Aid on my donation")

  await card.waitFor({state: "visible"});
  await card.click({force: true});
  await cardholder.fill("Tester O'Doh-erty");
  await cardnumber.waitFor({state: "visible"});
  
  await giftaid.check();
```

How can I fix this?

I get the following timeout error:

```
Test timeout of 30000ms exceeded.
Error: locator.waitFor: Page closed
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for getByRole('textbox', { name: 'credit-card-number' }) to be visible
============================================================

  70 |   await cardholder.fill("Tester O'Doh-erty");
  71 |
> 72 |   await cardnumber.waitFor({state: "visible"});
     |                    ^
  73 |   
  74 |   await giftaid.check();
  75 |
```

Comment: Do you need it to be visible?

Comment: Yes I do. I have tried to make it wait to be visible but still no luck

Comment: Probably not the main problem, but don't forget to add an `await` on your `page.waitForTimeout(10000)`. By my above comment, I meant to suggest that you may be able to type in it without visibility. What's the high-level goal here?